# This limits problem doesn't seem to have a "correct" answer?

Tags: limits

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{(x+3x^2)^{1/3}-x^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}}\right)$$

I was able to evaluate the answer to be 0, by splitting the denominator for the both the numerators, and simplifying the term within the bracket and the term at the end separately - and simply substituting 0 in the end. However, the answer, apparently, is 1. Would appreciate a solution or any explanation :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The correct answer is $0$, as you say.

Comment: @TonyK Really? I mean I'm not exactly the best at math, and the source of this question (and the answer) is pretty reputed, so I doubted myself. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Write it as $\lim_{x\to 0} \left( (1 + 3 x)^{1/3} - 1 \right)$ and it's obvious.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yep, that was my approach. Thank you!

Comment: It is of course 0 as you done it well @NitinReddy.

Comment: If you changed the denominator to $x^{4/3}$ then you would get a limit of $1$ as $x \to 0$